# Javascript Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 How to avoid and fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.yml`like following

```
version: '3'

services:
  api-server:
    build: ./api
    links:
      - 'db'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./api:/src
      - ./src/node_modules
    tty: true
    container_name: api-server

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    volumes:
      - './db:/config'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    container_name: db
```

And then I tried

`docker-compose build`

`docker-compose up -d`

`$ docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
567e1e7463d        api-server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago        Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp              api-server
e85e746d699        db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago          Up 21 hours         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   db
```

And then I'd like to test `Post` method to `api-server` but some error returned.

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Therefore I tried to know the cause of this to enter `api-server` in `docker`

`docker exec -it api-server sh`

And I launch `api-server` internally

`npm run start`

And then tried to `POST` to `api-server`

But the following error displayed in console.

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`

What is the cause of this?

The port 3000 was already used when `docker-compose up -d' ?

How to avoid this error?

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: instead of starting server from inside docker when compose is up, make compose down then turn up the compose nd try becz your main issue is with 500 server error so check docker logs for api server

Answer (score 0):

There's already an instance of your Node application running (as the main container process) so when you `npm run start` a second one in a debugging shell you'll get that "address already in use" error.  You'll get the same error without Docker if you try to start the server twice in two separate terminal windows.

If you're trying to actively debug the program, I'd suggest using a host Node installation, which will generally be more convenient.  Or if you really need two copies of the server, run them in two separate containers; you can use `docker compose run api-server ...` to get a new container with largely the same setup as the existing container (notably, without published ports) but a different command.